# ImportError: cannot import name parse_date while importing Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    import pandas.testing
  File "/home/suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas._testing import (
  File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 4, in init pandas._testing (pandas/src/testing.c:4068)
  File "/home/suman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/types/missing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas import lib
  File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 1, in init pandas.lib (pandas/lib.c:87552)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 67, in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:109851)
ImportError: cannot import name parse_date
```

Comment: have you installed pandas? if yes try `pip install pandas --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed pandas in the proper directiry:

```
pip install pandas
```

If you have already done so, it would be worth upgrading pandas:

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same error today when I developed a pyqt project. I found there are two "pandas" when I uninstalled one then tried to install again. What I have done was uninstalling both two "pandas", then install the latest version, then it works. Although I solved this on Windows, but hope it is helpful to you.