# cannot import name parse_date on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when i'm just importing pandas on Python 3.6.9 this error happens but when importing pandas on python 2.7 it just work fine.

```
import pandas as pd
```

> this is the console output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 177, in <module>
import pandas.testing
File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/testing.py", line 5, in <module>
from pandas._testing import (
File "pandas/src/testing.pyx", line 4, in init pandas._testing (pandas/src/testing.c:4441)
File "/home/amir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/types/missing.py", line 5, in <module>
from pandas import lib
File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 1, in init pandas.lib (pandas/lib.c:90894)
File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 68, in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:116506)

ImportError: cannot import name parse_date
```

can you suggest what to do beside using python 2.7?

Comment: What is pandas version? Maybe use some oldier, so you can try upgrade pandas.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is an install issue.  Have you checked your environments? Maybe try updating/reinstalling pandas. Or (if possible) run in py3.7 which I've generally found to have fewer conflicts.

Comment: @jezrael pandas version is 1.1.5

Comment: I think idea from @CreekGeek is really good.

Comment: @CreekGeek I have tried to reinstalling pandas but nothing changes and I haven't try this on py3.7

Comment: First, this thread is duplicated: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790050/importerror-cannot-import-name-parse-date-while-importing-pandas
Second, I tried to install Pandas 1.1.5 on Python 3.6.9 and it worked so you should create new environment and install them from scratch.

Comment: @CreekGeek I  tried it on py 3.7 and it  worked , thanks .

Comment: @ThangM.Pham there wasn't answer for my problem so I asked here